# Is it possible to add custom tools to a PKToolPicker?

Tags: swift, pencilkit

If I draw for example with the Notes app I can see that there is a custom tool that can be used for handwriting. Now in my case I don't want to implement handwriting, but I need a custom tool that I can use to draw elements like arrows. In short, I need a cutomizable pencil that would allow me to detect touches and to draw directly by reading them.

Now if I read the *PKTool* documentation, it says:

```
Don’t adopt this protocol in your own objects. Instead, create a tool object to provide users with the desired the tool behavior.
```

But there is only a predefined set of tools. Is it possible to implement my own tool like in the Notes app?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out @Ramy? There's so little documentation (and content) around PencilKit... I don't understand the "Instead, create a tool object to provide users with the desired the tool behavior." of the docs =(